# Is There an Efficient Method of Checking Which Letter is Being Used?

Tags: c++, string, letter

Let's say I have a string `string str;`, and it has any number of letters in it, and I want to count how many of each letter is in the string. For example, the word `"Example"` has 2 `'e'`, 1 `'x'`, 1 `'a'`, 1 `'m'`, 1 `'p'`, and 1 `'l'`. Is there a more efficient way of checking for each of these letters than this?

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    if (str.at(i) == 'a')
    {
        //variable which keeps track of a ++
    }...
    //25 more of that for each other letter
}
```

It feels like there has to be a more efficient way of doing this, but I have no idea how. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Use array the size of the ascii table and then you can easily count every character. array[character]++

Comment: Or rather `array[(unsigned char)character]`, since `char`s may or may not be signed.

Comment: On a side note: using `at()` is overkill in this example, since the `for` loop ensures that it won't go out of bounds of the string, so no need to bounds check each character. Use `str[i]` instead of `str.at(i)`

Comment: @Wahalez -- close, but use the number of possible values that `char` can hold, i.e., `1u << CHAR_BIT`. The character encoding doesn't matter during counting.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `std::map` for example:

```
#include <map>

std::map<char, std::size_t> mCount{};
for (auto ch : str)
{
   ++mCount[ch];
}
```

Using a `std::array` (which has the advantage of the data being contiguous in memory, thereby improving cache performance) you can write:

```
#include <array>
#include <limits>

constexpr auto nNumChars = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) + 1;
std::array<std::size_t, nNumChars> arCounts{};

for (auto ch : str) {
   ++arCounts[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
}
```

Comment: You might want to increase array size to `256`.

Comment: Only if `char` are unsigned. Otherwise, there's UB on negative chars

Comment: You're all correct, of course. Typed it up in a hurry between other things. Adapted accordingly and removed array example.

Comment: @Jeffrey That's why you should cast to `unsigned char` first.

Comment: An array of 256, with `ch` cast to some `unsigned` would have made your array answer excellent.

Comment: @DrewDormann I still think 256 is a bit risky on a system with 64 bit bytes.

Comment: For portability's sake, I believe the array size need to be `(2 << CHAR_BIT) - 1`.  This will cover cases where you have a larger than 8 bit `char`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Even that will be problematic if `CHAR_BIT` is 64 :-) (btw, you mean `1 << CHAR_BIT` right)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Plus a `static_assert` to check for potential overflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

I especially like `multisets` for this.

Initialization from `string` is straight away.

Walking the set is not so clean.

https://godbolt.org/z/soccz8Tnn

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"The quick fox jumped over the green fence"};

    // Easy initialization from string
    std::multiset<char> st(cbegin(str), cend(str));

    // Printing the count for each different key is a bit more difficult
    for (auto it{cbegin(st)}; it != cend(st); it = st.upper_bound(*it))
    {
        std::cout << "st[" << *it << "] = " << st.count(*it) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it perform a heap allocation for each character? (any character, not only unique ones) :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not sure, but it could easily be that way, yes. I understood OP's reference to efficiency as avoiding writing 26 `if` blocks; and, in that sense, `multiset` is hardly beatable. But I agree that an `array` solution is not much more complicated, and indeed more efficient (for insertions/lookup/memory usage).